# Returning different values for 0 and for an empty field in a PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf

Sorry if this is a silly question - I'm pretty new to Javascript.
I'm trying to make a PDF with auto-calculating form fields, and I need a way to differentiate between a '0' and no entered value.

I'm basically trying to compare two fields.

Let's say: 
Field A is 2 and Field B is 0, Field C should compare them and see if Field B is higher than Field A. If it is, then Field A will be added to a total in Field C.

If Field B is lower than Field A, then the difference between them will be taken away, and the remainder of Field A will be added. (i.e. Field A is 5 and Field B is 2, then 3 will be taken away from Field A to make it the same as Field B, and only 2 will be added to Field C)

But I need some way to make a difference between when '0' is entered into Field B, and when the field just isn't touched/left blank.
Here's what I have (It's probably a mess):

```
    dex = Number(this.getField("DEX").value);
    dexCap = Number(this.getField("ACAP").value);

    dexAdd = 0;
    if(dex < dexCap) dexAdd = dex;
    else if(dexCap==null) dexAdd = dex;
    else if(dexCap=="0") dexAdd = 0;
    else dexAdd = dexCap;

    event.value = Number(dexAdd) + Number(this.getField("ACPROF").value) + 
    Number(this.getField("ACITEM").value) + 10;
```

I don't know if there's a way to do it. (I've been searching for a while now - thought it best to just ask).

Comment: Can you provide more context or a better, reproducible example? You mention Fields A, B, and C but it's not clear what those are in your code. Also, you are converting everything to numbers right away - you probably need to check if they are empty first.

Comment: Hey, yeah - sorry!
I'm making an RPG sheet, and there's a stat - Armour Class (In the code above, this is equal to the event.value. (But I believe we only need to touch dexAdd?)
So when you wear armour, you can add your Dexterity (DEX in the above) to this, but depending on your armour type, there's a certain cap to which you can add your Dexterity. (So like above, if you had +5 DEX, but were wearing a type of armour which only allowed up to +2, you would only get +2 from your DEX, not the full +5).

RE: The checking - I thought that could be contained within the dexAdd 'if' statement, no?

Comment: So in the above, I need to check whether ACAP (dexCap) says nothing, in which case, make it equal DEX (dex).
Or, if it equals "0", then make sure dex does not get added at all (as there's a type of armour which allows 0 DEX bonus).

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert dexCap to a number first if you need to check if it was empty. Because of JavaScript's coercion rules, an empty string `""` will be converted to 0 when you try to convert it to a number. Take the value as it is and factor out the null/undefined/empty check first. Also, you should always declare variables with `var`, `let`, or `const`, to avoid creating global variables.

```
let dex = Number(this.getField("DEX").value);
let dexCap = this.getField("ACAP").value);
let dexAdd = 0;

if (dexCap === null || dexCap === undefined || dexCap.trim() === "") {
    dexAdd = dex;
} else {
    dexCap = Number(dexCap);

    if (dex < dexCap) dexAdd = dex;
    else if(dexCap === 0) dexAdd = 0;
    else dexAdd = dexCap;
}


event.value = Number(dexAdd) + Number(this.getField("ACPROF").value) + 
Number(this.getField("ACITEM").value) + 10;
```

Comment: Thank you!
I was able to rejig it a bit. It still detects an empty field as 0, but I found a workaround, so I think it's alright!